# Dragon Age Inquisition can't figure out what my character is

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've imported a custom world state using Dragon Age Keep and I setup a character as a male elven wizard.  The game started off with rogue gear and I'm hearing duplicate spoken audio whenever a player gender reference occurs.  After the first combat encounter, my character is stripped of visible gear with a bow in inventory.  Clearly I've encountered some kind of bug.  Is there a known work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this can be caused by a corrupt world state.  Importing a new world file from the Dragon Age Keep website and starting a new game fixed this issue.